# Sampling Time for ADC on STM32L432

Tags: stm32, adc

I'm looking for guidance on how to select the Sampling Time for the ADC on my STM32L432KCU6.  I found some tables in AN2834, but they are for the STM32H7 Series. I'm interested in getting ±0.5 LSB accuracy with 12-bit resolution.  I'm running my ADC clock at 32 MHz.

One question I have is whether the ADC discharges (resets) the internal capacitor (C-adc) between every sample or not. If it does, then that tells me that I need to give the circuit enough time to charge C-adc up from 0 to the target voltage, with the worst-case time being when the target voltage is Vref (3 volts).

With my current configuration, I noticed that as I increase the voltage presented to the ADC, the counts value stops increasing near ~4086 which is less than the maximum value of 4095. Does this mean that my Sampling Time is too low?

Also, how do I determine Sampling Time for the internal Channel Temperature Sensor (IN17)?

Here's what I tried: With Sampling Time for all channels set to 12.5 cycles and maximizing the voltage applied to one of the ADC channels, the highest counts I see for that channel are ~4086. When I changed the Sample Time to 24.5 cycles, the highest counts I see for that channel are ~3856. I expected the longer Sampling Time to allow the counts value to go higher, but instead they were unexpectedly lower.

Comment: I don't know specifically for STM32, but ADC max precision is usually arround the middle of the range, the extremes are not so good (or outright terrible).

Answer (score 1):

> One question I have is whether the ADC discharges (resets) the
> internal capacitor (C-adc) between every sample or not.

No. And you cannot assume anything about its state, it may be influenced by previous sample, i.e. it is not necessarily true that:

> worst-case time being when the target voltage is Vref (3 volts)

Have a look also at the errata (I don't know if the 1ms erratum applies to this particular model), and make sure you have [calibrated ADC before use](http://www.efton.sk/STM32/gotcha/g149.html).

The increased error at higher sampling time is unexpected, so that maybe requires some further investigation: describe your hardware (is it a "known good" hardware like Nucleo? How exactly are VREF+/VDDA/VSSA connected, are they rock stable? What are the voltages involved? Post a minimal but complete compilable example exhibiting the problem.

> Also, how do I determine Sampling Time for the internal Channel
> Temperature Sensor (IN17)?

Given in Datasheet. Even throwing in calibration values etc., don't expect precisions [below several deg.C](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/stm-32f4-reading-cpu-temperature/), though.

JW